# Creating a .sh wrapper in my debian package

Tags: debian, packaging, mono

I'm trying to build a debian package for a program that uses mono. My `make install` target currently puts all of my binaries `/usr/local/lib/mypackage`, then creates a tiny executable script in `/usr/local/bin` that invokes the actual binaries with mono. I use a one-liner to replace the placeholder `PREFIX` with the actual install path:

```
install: DESTDIR=/usr/local
install: LIBDIR=$(DESTDIR)/lib
install: BINDIR=$(DESTDIR)/bin
install: $(PHONIX) $(ANTLR) doc
    install -m 0755 -d $(LIBDIR)/phonix
    install -m 0755 -t $(LIBDIR)/phonix $(PHONIX) $(ANTLER)
    install -m 0755 -D phonix.sh $(BINDIR)/phonix
    sed -i "s!PREFIX!$(LIBDIR)!" $(BINDIR)/phonix
```

When I'm running under `dh_make`, `$(LIBDIR)` and `$(BINDIR)` point to the packaging directory as desired. Everything gets installed into the right place for the packager, but the `sed` call puts the path of my local packaging directory into the script, which then gets placed verbatim in the package. This obviously doesn't work once I actually install the package on the target system.

I think that I need to move the `sed` call into the post-install script, but I'm not sure how to get the local install directory (the moral equivalent of my `$(LIBDIR)` and `$(BINDIR)`) in the post-install step. Or is there a better way altogether to do this?

---

**Edit**: Here's my actual `phonix.sh` file, before sed is called:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

exec mono PREFIX/phonix.exe
```

As you can see, the *only* purpose of this file is to provide an executable wrapper for the mono-based .exe. The sed call just replaces `PREFIX` with the value of `$(LIBDIR)`. So all I really need to know is *how can I get the actual installed location of my .exe on the target system* so that the wrapper script works?

Comment: Is your debian package going to put files in `/usr/local/bin`? If so, it shouldn't.

Comment: @Faheem, well my `make install` puts them in `/usr/local/bin`. When I run `dh_make` it puts them in `$(DESTDIR)/bin`, which I believe means they'll actually go in `/usr/bin` when the .deb is installed. I could be wrong about this -- I've never built a .deb file before.

Comment: Can you explain what your sed call is doing? If it is rewriting your script after installation it is a bad idea. Why do you need to do that? What is this PREFIX for? Are you writing a rules file and using debhelper? You should set your variables in the rules file. You are reading the packaging documentation, right?

Comment: @Faheem, Yes to all of your questions, for better or worse. I've edited the question with my actual .sh file, which hopefully clears things up.

Comment: I'm not sure why PREFIX is required at all. The usual way these things work is `exec mono phonix.exe` and mono looks in a standard location for phonix. Disclaimer: I don't know a thing about mono.

Comment: @Faheem, mono's standard location is the GAC, but application libraries aren't supposed to go into the GAC. I'm following the mono app deployment guidelines here: http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment.

Comment: Maybe I'll just use a relative path. Is there any situation where the stuff I put in `bin` and the stuff I put in `lib` won't share a parent directory?

Comment: I suggest, first, talking to the Debian Mono maintainers, namely Debian Mono Group <pkg-mono-group@lists.alioth.debian.org>. This is a mailing list, you could just send mail to it. Alternatively, I suggest treating your regular install differently from your Debian packaging. For your Debian package, you know what the final path needs to be, so you can just have `debian/rules` manually write `phonix.sh` to `debian/packagename/usr/bin/` with the correct path, and not put the `phonix.sh` in there, or just write over it. This is an ugly hack. The mono people may be able to suggest something sane.

Comment: See also http://pkg-mono.alioth.debian.org/. IRC is generally a good way to get this kind of info.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `DESTDIR` in a nonstandard way.  It is not the installation prefix of your package, it's the "fakeroot" prefix for things such as package builds.

The more typical way to write this is something like this:

```
prefix = /usr/local
bindir = $(prefix)/bin
libdir = $(prefix)/lib

install: $(PHONIX) $(ANTLR) doc
    install -m 0755 -d $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/phonix
    install -m 0755 -t $(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/phonix $(PHONIX) $(ANTLER)
    install -m 0755 -D phonix.sh $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/phonix
    sed -i "s!PREFIX!$(libdir)!" $(DESTDIR)$(bindir)/phonix
```

Leave `DESTDIR` empty in the makefile of your package.  It should be set in `debian/rules` or automatically by dh or cdbs.  I guess from your question that it does get set somehow.